# My function is copying a PGM image file to PPM in a different way

Tags: c, image, ppm, pgm

I have a very simple function that saves a PPM image:

```
void WriteCImage(CImage *cimg, char *filename)
{
    FILE *fp;
    int i,n;

    fp = fopen(filename,"w");
    fprintf(fp,"P6\n");
    fprintf(fp,"%d %d\n",cimg->C[0]->ncols,cimg->C[0]->nrows);
    fprintf(fp,"255\n"); 
    n = cimg->C[0]->ncols*cimg->C[0]->nrows;
    for (i=0; i < n; i++) 
    {
        fputc(cimg->C[0]->val[i],fp);
        fputc(cimg->C[1]->val[i],fp);
        fputc(cimg->C[2]->val[i],fp);
    }
    fclose(fp);
}
```

as you can see, this function receives a matrix (in CImage format) and writes the image data in the ASCII file. It seems correct, but every time I copy a grayscale image to a PPM image I have problems. Look at the code:

```
//that's a PGM grayscale image
gt = ReadImage(argv[1]);

//creating an RGB image with same dimensions of the PGM image
nwcimg = CreateCImage(gt->nrows,gt->ncols);

n=gt->nrows*gt->ncols;

//iterate through the PGM image
for(index=0;index<n;index++)  
{
    // just a copy of the grayscale image value to all 3 layeres    
    //of the PPM (RGB) image    
    nwcimg->C[0]->val[index]=gt->val[index];
    nwcimg->C[1]->val[index]=gt->val[index];
    nwcimg->C[2]->val[index]=gt->val[index];
}


WriteCImage(nwcimg,"gt-copied.ppm"); 
DestroyCImage(&nwcimg);
DestroyImage(&gt);
```

what problem i have? well, the code seems correct and simple. But when the cimage matrix/vector is written as a file, i can see that the two pictures are not the same. Seems like the pixels of the PGM image are 'shifted' or 'mirrored' in the copied image.

You can see the [Image File](http://www.ic.unicamp.br/~anselmoferreira/images/gt.pgm) and [The RGB copy](http://www.ic.unicamp.br/~anselmoferreira/images/gt-copy.ppm)

Answer (score 2):

Shouldn't

```
for(index=0;index<n;index++) {
    nwcimg->C[0]->val[index]=gt->val[index];
    nwcimg->C[1]->val[index]=gt->val[index];
    nwcimg->C[2]->val[index]=gt->val[index];
```

be

```
for(index=0;index<n;index) {
    nwcimg->C[0]->val[index]=gt->val[index++];
    nwcimg->C[1]->val[index]=gt->val[index++];
    nwcimg->C[2]->val[index]=gt->val[index++];
```

?  The `for` loop in your file writer writes 3 bytes per loop.  The loop in your reader consumes only 1 byte per loop then copies it into three separate arrays.

Comment: I will try your suggestion. Seems smart.

Comment: This command slightly shifts the image to the right position, but the image is not the same yet. I think maybe its necessary to increase more the index variable. The maximum i got is increasing the index by 1000, higher than this value returns me a segmentation fault :-(.